# Can I use CSS to change a bookmark's properties when its link is being hovered over?

Tags: html, css

If I have a simple HTML and CSS document using bookmarks (named links) and ordinary links, is it possible to alter a bookmark (eg. change its color) when its link is being hovered over.

For example, if I have the following HTML

```
...
<a name="bookmark1">Bookmark One</a>
<a name="bookmark2">Bookmark Two</a>
<a name="bookmark3">Bookmark Three</a>
...
<a href="#bookmark1">Link to BM#1</a>
...
```

can I write CSS along the lines of:

```
a:hover
{
    "the bookmark's color": red
}
```

which would have the effect of changing the bookmark's font (and not its link's) color to red? That is, the text "Bookmark One" changes color, not "Link to BM#1".

UPDATE: thanks to everyone who answered. In summary, it seems you can't affect the target of a link while hovering over it using just CSS. You need to resort to javascript. For my simple purposes I didn't want to go the trouble, so I selected the answer that was CSS only but required clicking on the link.

Comment: How do the elements appear in the mark-up? Could you post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us what you're working with?

Comment: I think everyone's answer so far is missing the point, but I could be mistaken. The way I understand it, OP wants the **target** of the link to change color, not the link itself. As in: `a[href="#my_element"]:hover{/* change the element with name or id "my_element"'s color */}`

Comment: Wesley is correct. Can the target of the link be affected using just CSS (ie. no jQuery)? And remember there's many bookmarks and links in the document.

Comment: "Bookmark One" & "Link to BM#1" are in same div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) but the source order will have to be different, the links that reference the named links must come before the named links since your selector is targeting the named links.

```
<a href="#bookmark1">Link to BM#1</a>
<a href="#bookmark2">Link to BM#2</a>

<a name="bookmark1">Bookmark One</a>
<a name="bookmark2">Bookmark Two</a>
<a name="bookmark3">Bookmark Three</a>
```

Another problem with this is that since there aren't variables or back-references in CSS you must explicitly make a CSS selector for each of the links you want to do this with.

```
a:hover[href="#bookmark1"] ~ a[name="bookmark1"],
a:hover[href="#bookmark2"] ~ a[name="bookmark2"] {
    color: red;
}
```

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/L2wfR/2/)

You'll notice in Example 1 "bookmark3" doesn't highlight since there is no rule referencing it.

A much more general and easier to maintain approach would be to highlight the named link after the link to it was clicked instead of on hover.  You could do this with a simple `:target` selector

```
a:target {
    color: red;
}
```

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/M94An/)

If you are absolutely married to the idea that it must be on hover and don't mind using JavaScript you could do it with a little bit of jQuery:

```
$('a[href^="#bookmark"]').hover(function() {
    // grab target of this link and remove the leading hash
    var name = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*#/, '');
    $('a[name="' + name + '"]').addClass('highlightedbookmark');
}, function() {
    // grab target of this link and remove the leading hash
    var name = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*#/, '');
    $('a[name="' + name + '"]').removeClass('highlightedbookmark');
});
```

[Example 3](http://jsfiddle.net/z9kj7/)

Better yet this solution doesn't have the HTML source order restrictions that the pure CSS method does: [Example 4](http://jsfiddle.net/z9kj7/1/)

Comment: I went with the solution from Example 1. It seems you can't effect the target while hovering using just CSS. You need to resort to javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the ellipses in your question imply the location of your bookmarks, and they are the immediately following sibling of the links, you can use the adjacent-sibling selector:

```
div:hover + div {
    color: blue;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8b6cA/2/)

Reference:

- [adjacent-sibling selector (CSS2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but feared it was a bit too convenient to be the case.

Comment: @Wesley: yeah, it seems unlikely to be this easy, doesn't it? But without further guidance/information this is the best I can think of. With JavaScript it'd be easier, and jQuery easier still...one day, CSS will include behavioural logic, I'm sure...

Comment: Well, you can [get carried away](http://jsfiddle.net/8b6cA/3/) with the adjacent selector if there's a bunch of other stuff in the way, I wish we could select parents of elements / step backwards.

Comment: Unfortunately the ellipses do not imply and nice ordering. I've edit ed the question to be a bit more explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the color tag to alter the color of text. It'd be also better if you use an id or class.

```
a:hover{ 
    color:red;
 }

#bookmark a:hover{ 
    color:red;
 }
```

**EDIT**

In case the text to be changes is different from the link text then you can use jQuery to do it, ex:

```
  $("#boomkark-link").hover( function(){
    $("#bookmark").css('color', 'RED');
  }
```

Comment: This would select the link itself (albeit only if present within the element of an `id` of `bookmark`), **not** the 'bookmark' as asked for in the question.

Comment: Like is it that the bookmark is a different entity other than the link?

Comment: It seems that way, yes; mainly because the question specifically states: "the effect of changing the bookmark's font (and not its link's) color to red."

Comment: I think each link would link to a different bookmark, though?

Comment: hmm. Maybe, but just showing an example of how this could be done in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class to the bookmark link. See the below example:

**HTML**

```
<a name="bookmark1" class="bookmark">Bookmark One</a>

<a href="#bookmark1">Link to BM#1</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a:hover{
    color: red;
}

a.bookmark:hover{
    color: blue;
}
```

That way your normal links will hover RED (in this example) and your bookmark links will hover BLUE.

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute selector:

```
a[name]:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the name attribute selector is not fully cross browser supported. Good option though =)

Comment: This would select the link itself, **not** the 'bookmark' as asked for in the question.

Answer (score 0):

@dave; may be you can define it with simple `css declaration`.

```
.wrap1 a, .wrap2 a{
    background:green;
}
.wrap1 a:hover, .wrap2 a:hover{
    background:red;
}
a{background:yellow;}
a:hover{background:pink;}
```

If the links are in different `divs` & you want to target an specific `a` tag. 
check this for more http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/RsmAg/
**EDIT:**
may be `nth-child` is also an option. Check [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/3aMC5/)